# Create topic Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I try to create the topic in Kafka.

I follow [this](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart_createtopic) guide, but it fails.

This error is
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RYa4.jpg)

```
Error while executing topic command replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0
kafka.admin.AdminOperationException: replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0
    at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.assignReplicasToBrokers(AdminUtils.scala:70)
    at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.createTopic(AdminUtils.scala:171)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.createTopic(TopicCommand.scala:93)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:55)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Since you do get a response from the server, I would start by examining the  output of the command: bin/kafka-server-start.sh, there should probably be an indication of why the broker failed to execute. If it is not clear add the output to the question.

Comment: You should first run kafka server then only you should move to create topic. looks like no kafka server is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
kafka.admin.AdminOperationException: replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0
```

It is saying you have 0 brokers available. So make sure you have atlease 1 kafka-broker running. You will get this exception when you have `number of brokers running < replication-factor`.

Answer (score 0):

while setting up kafka(single machine with multiple brokers) keep this is in mind,
 Each server.properties file in $kafka_home/config configured with different broker id and port number will act as an individual broker.
If you have two server.properties files e.g: server1.properties and server2.properties in the config folder with different broker id values and port numbers then you have two brokers.
And the replication factor of your topics should always be less than or equal to your  number of brokers.

```
replication factor <= no. of brokers
```

When looking at your error, i can say there is no kafka broker configured. Check your server.properties file once. Or else paste it in the question so i can look in to it.